# Splitting a data.frame by sequences of NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, split, na

I would like to split a data.frame by sequences of NA values. The original data.frame looks like this example:

```
data <- data.frame(temp1=c(2,5,8,NA,NA,NA,7,4,1,3,NA,NA,1,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,9),temp2=c(1:19))
```

and I would like to get a list of data frames with only the sequences of NA values:

```
result <- list(data.frame(temp1=c(NA,NA,NA),temp2=c(4,5,6)),data.frame(temp1=c(NA,NA),temp2=c(11,12)),data.frame(temp1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA),temp2=c(15,16,17,18)))
```

so that I can work on each sequence independently (each sequence is a specific case).

(e.g like a `subset(data,is.na(data$temp1))` but with separated sequences of NA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An one-liner using `split` would be:

```r
# library(data.table) for the rleid() function
# interchangeable with dplyr::consecutive_id()
library(data.table) 

split(data, ifelse(is.na(data$temp1), rleid(data$temp1), NA))

$`4`
  temp1 temp2
4    NA     4
5    NA     5
6    NA     6

$`9`
   temp1 temp2
11    NA    11
12    NA    12

$`12`
   temp1 temp2
15    NA    15
16    NA    16
17    NA    17
18    NA    18
```

Wrap the whole thing with `unname()` if you want to get rid of the list names.

Comment: This is the best an easiest solution, as I'm already using library "data.table" in my script!

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `consecutive_id` (**dplyr** >= 1.1.0) for grouping and `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(grp = consecutive_id(temp1)) %>% 
  filter(is.na(temp1)) %>% 
  group_split(.keep=F) %>% 
  as.list()
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  temp1 temp2
  <dbl> <int>
1    NA     4
2    NA     5
3    NA     6

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  temp1 temp2
  <dbl> <int>
1    NA    11
2    NA    12

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  temp1 temp2
  <dbl> <int>
1    NA    15
2    NA    16
3    NA    17
4    NA    18
```